# How to align the Scrollable tabs with the keyline in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I'am using the TabLayout to implements a scrollable tabs. In the material design guildline(https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs), it suggest “The left-most tab content aligns with the keyline”, the picture:
[image]

I try to add a attribute paddingLeft, but it's not right. So, as the guideline describe, what can I do to implement that? Any help please!

Answer (score 7):

Use `app:tabContentStart="60dp"` in your TabLayout xml file. Because the guidelines state 72dp between the left edge of the screen to where the title of the first tab starts, and because all tab titles are left- and right-padded 12dp, you'll need 60dp. For example:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabContentStart="60dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"/>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer although app:tabContentStart="72dp"  aligns with the keyline for me and app:tabContentStart="16dp" makes it align correctly with the navitaionIcon! Thanks!!